# Continuity of $\sin^{-1}(x+y) + \ln(xy)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have to determine the interval where is this function continuous:

$$f(x,y) = \sin^{-1}(x+y) + \ln(xy)$$

I did the following:

Let $g(x,y) = x+y $ and $h(x,y) = xy$. Also $j(x) = \sin^{-1}(x)$ and $k(x) = \ln(x)$.

Then, $f = j(g(x,y)) + k(h(x,y))$ and it is continuous. But if I try to graph $f(x,y) = \sin^{-1}(x+y) + \ln(xy)$ it doesn't exist. Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful; the function is not defined everywhere. Indeed, if $|x+y| > 1$, then $\sin^{-1}$ does not exist, and the same holds if $xy \leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. So taking into consideration those restrictions. It would only be continuous in $[0,1]$?

Comment: A function of two variables $x,y$ would be continuous in some region of the plane.  Not "continuous in $[0,1]$".

Comment: Then, how can one express where it is continuous? Or is it not at all?

Comment: It is continuous everywhere where it is defined. Your original argument applies to the regions in which the function is defined, and so the function is continuous on the intersection of $|x+y| \leq 1$ and $xy > 0$.